# Cannot run .x86 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, software-installation, helpfile

Hi I tried a lot of different way to get this solved spent the whole day no luck.. 
I've tried executing file as program double clicking it doesn't lunch

```
chmod +x /LiveCodeCommunityinstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86
```

then

```
./LiveCodeCommunityinstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86
```

A lot seems not to work on 14.04 AND I really want to make Livecode work I have to program.. Thank you for your generous future understanding and comprehension of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your command was wrong. Instead of `chmod +x /LiveCodeCommunityinstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86` issue: `chmod +x LiveCodeCommunityinstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86`.
After that you can run it.

**Explanation:** with the `/` it points to the root of the filesystem, without to the actual directory. You can verify if the flag was set with `ls -la LiveCodeCommunityinstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86` command. If it shows `x` flag, than the command was successful. Alternatively you can run it without setting the `x` flag like this: `sh LiveCodeCommunityinstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86`.

Comment: It executed your command properly, I clicked twice on it,still didn’t run nor the right click then run on the icon..

Comment: What error message do you get when you enter `./LiveCodeCommunityinstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86` ?

Comment: once I entered your command : ls -la LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86
-rwxrwxr-x 1 xgracious xgracious 49743316 May  6 21:07 LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86 then sh LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86
LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86: 1: LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: Error that I got : ./LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86: error while loading shared libraries: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: That would be `sudo apt-get install libfreetype`.

Comment: Well it's 5:22am , I hope you guys have some great ideas for me. Thanks again all of you (going to take a nap) ! :)

Comment: sudo apt-get install libfreetype , Unable to locate package libfreetype, I've tried libfreetype6, but it says libfreetype6 it is already the newest version.

Comment: A bit of googling turned up [this](http://ftp.runrev.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14824&p=73331). Is your system 64bits? You may need to install a couple of other packages first in that case.

Comment: Hi Jos, yes my system is 64 :)

Comment: No luck did all there commands still ended up with ./LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86
./LiveCodeCommunityInstaller-6_5_0-Linux.x86: error while loading shared libraries: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Issue: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 &&
sudo apt-get update  &&
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk && sudo apt-get install libfreetype6`, and check after that.

Comment: Hi Frantique your commmands worked until it got to "sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk" where it displayed an error saying Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate, so I replaced it by sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0, still didn’t do the job wasn't able to run the .x86  , I'm starting to think I'm doomed. Thank you for your tryings

Comment: Well, sorry... I am still using 32bit version, so I couldn't test the command. :( So, the goal is to install somehow the 32bit support on your system, after that you can install the missing package.